# Why is not removing properly from the **JSON** array?

Tags: sql, json

I have a **JSON** array, I want to give an entry and this entry should be removed from the **JSON** array.

For example, the array:

```
SET @os ='[
{
    "id": "66",
    "date_end": "2022-01-09 18:00:00",
    "occupied": "1",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-09 17:30:00",
    "idCategory": "[1,2,3]",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-02 14:59:27"
},
{
    "id": "39",
    "date_end": "2022-01-03 11:30:00",
    "occupied": "1",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-03 08:00:00",
    "idCategory": "3",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-01 22:40:58"
}
]';
```

And the entry that I want to be removed:

```
SET @test ='
{
    "id": "39",
    "date_end": "2022-01-03 11:30:00",
    "occupied": "1",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-03 08:00:00",
    "idCategory": "3",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-01 22:40:58"
}';
```

My code is something like:

```
SET @new_os = (select json_arrayagg(js) from json_table(@os, '$[*]' columns ( js json path '$')) as jt 
    where json_extract(js, '$.date_end') <> json_extract(@test, '$.date_end') and json_extract(js, '$.id') <> json_extract(@test, '$.id') 
    and json_extract(js, '$.date_begin') <> json_extract(@test, '$.date_begin') and json_extract(js, '$.date_requested') <> json_extract(@test, '$.date_requested') 
    and json_extract(js, '$.idCategory') <> json_extract(@test, '$.idCategory') and json_extract(js, '$.occupied') <> json_extract(@test, '$.occupied'));

SELECT @os,@new_os;
```

But in the end I get that **@new_os** is **NULL**, and it should be:

```
[
{
    "id": "66",
    "date_end": "2022-01-09 18:00:00",
    "occupied": "1",
    "date_begin": "2022-01-09 17:30:00",
    "idCategory": "[1,2,3]",
    "date_requested": "2022-01-02 14:59:27"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filtering where the json columns don't match,
it could be filtering out where the columns do match.

> ```
> SET @new_os = (
> select json_pretty(json_arrayagg(os.js)) as new_os
> from json_table(@os, '$[*]' columns (js json path '$')) as os
> where not exists (
>   select 1
>   from json_table(@test, '$' columns ( js json path '$')) as tst
>   where json_extract(os.js, '$.id') = json_extract(tst.js, '$.id')
>     and json_extract(os.js, '$.date_end') = json_extract(tst.js, '$.date_end')
>     and json_extract(os.js, '$.date_begin') = json_extract(tst.js, '$.date_begin')
>     and json_extract(os.js, '$.date_requested') = json_extract(tst.js, '$.date_requested')
>     and json_extract(os.js, '$.idCategory') = json_extract(tst.js, '$.idCategory')
>     and json_extract(os.js, '$.occupied') = json_extract(tst.js, '$.occupied')
> ));
>
> SELECT @os, @new_os;
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0192fc7ff7716b8feabd4bcb4a49d1d8)*